# Merge dataframes based on interval condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
id start        end
1  20/06/88     24/07/89
1  27/07/89     13/04/93
1  14/04/93     6/09/95
2  3/01/92      11/02/94
2  30/03/94     16/04/96
2  17/04/96     18/08/97
```

that I would like to merge with this other dataframe

```
id date
1  26/08/88   
2  10/05/96
```

The resulting merged dataframe should look like this

```
id start        end         date
1  20/06/88     24/07/89    26/06/88
1  27/07/89     13/04/93    NA
1  14/04/93     6/09/95     NA
2  3/01/92      11/02/94    NA
2  30/03/94     16/04/96    NA
2  17/04/96     18/08/97    10/05/96
```

In practice I want to merge the two dataframes based on id and on the fact that date must lie within the interval spanned by the start and end vars of the first dataframe.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do this? I tried to use the fuzzyjoin package, but I have some memory issue..

Many thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sqldf` for complex joins:

```
require(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT df1.*,df2.date,df2.id as id2
      FROM df1
      LEFT JOIN df2 
      ON df1.id = df2.id AND
      df1.start < df2.date AND
      df1.end > df2.date")
```

Comment: If the end points were to be included in the interval then we could use `<=` and `>=` or write `df2.date between df1.start and df1.end`

Answer (score 2):

Might be a dupe, will remove when I found a good target. In the meantime, we could use `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(2:3, as.Date, "%d/%m/%y") %>%
    fuzzy_left_join(
        df2 %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%y")),
        by = c("id" = "id", "start" = "date", "end" = "date"),
        match_fun = list(`==`, `<`, `>`))
#  id.x      start        end id.y       date
#1    1 1988-06-20 1989-07-24    1 1988-08-26
#2    1 1989-07-27 1993-04-13   NA       <NA>
#3    1 1993-04-14 1995-09-06   NA       <NA>
#4    2 1992-01-03 1994-02-11   NA       <NA>
#5    2 1994-03-30 1996-04-16   NA       <NA>
#6    2 1996-04-17 1997-08-18    2 1996-05-10
```

All that remains is tidying up the `id` columns.

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
id start        end
1  20/06/88     24/07/89
1  27/07/89     13/04/93
1  14/04/93     6/09/95
2  3/01/92      11/02/94
2  30/03/94     16/04/96
2  17/04/96     18/08/97", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
id date
1  26/08/88
2  10/05/96   ", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Maurits. Actually fuzzy join is the way I was already following by myself, but I did not manage to get the desired outcome because of some memory issue.. The sqldf approach instead seems lighter from this point of view. Many thanks anyway